# Python using the numbers 1 through 10 in a functions equation

Tags: python

This function is supposed to calculate the answer for d and the problem I am having is I need to use the values 1 through 10 for t. I'm pretty sure I would use the range function for this but I am not exactly sure how to get the function to take the numbers 1 through 10. Here is my code so far:

```
g = 9.8
def fallingDistance(t):
  d = .5 * g * pow(t, 2)
  return round(d, 2)

t = 
d = fallingDistance(t)

for i in range (10):
    print("The falling distance = ", d)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for t in range(10):
    print("The falling distance in %d seconds is %s" %(t, fallingDistance(t)))
```

Output:

```
The falling distance in 0 seconds is 0.0
The falling distance in 1 seconds is 4.9
The falling distance in 2 seconds is 19.6
The falling distance in 3 seconds is 44.1
The falling distance in 4 seconds is 78.4
The falling distance in 5 seconds is 122.5
The falling distance in 6 seconds is 176.4
The falling distance in 7 seconds is 240.1
The falling distance in 8 seconds is 313.6
The falling distance in 9 seconds is 396.9
```